# how to check around a specific value in a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am having some trouble checking the values around a specific cell in a 2D array of booleans. I have tried to assume that the specific value we are checking is not at the edge or corner of the 2D array. I have set a for loop to iterate 8 times, because if the value we are checking around is not at the edge of the 2D array, then there will be 8 neighbors. Here is my function to get the number of cells that are true around a specific cell.

I would like to increment the `counter` variable for every value around (3,5) that is set to true.

When I run this code, my counter is returning 16. Yet there are not 16 true values surrounding the given cell, is my logic within the loop wrong?

```
int getNeighborCount(boolMatrix generation, int row, int col){ 


int counter = 0;
row = 3; //the cell we are checking around is at row 3, column 5
col = 5;

//8 neighbors
if (col > 0 && row > 0){
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
        if(generation.get(row - 1, col - 1)){
            counter++;
        } if(generation.get(row - 1, col)){
            counter++;
        } if(generation.get(row - 1, col + 1)){
            counter++;
        }  if(generation.get(row, col - 1)){
            counter++;
        }  if(generation.get(row, col + 1)){
            counter++;
        }  if(generation.get(row + 1, col - 1)){
            counter++;
        }  if(generation.get(row + 1, col)){
            counter++;
        }  if(generation.get(row + 1, col + 1)){
            counter++;
        }
    }

    cout << "counter is " << counter;
}
return counter;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

No need for a `for` loop here. It is actually wrong, because you have 8 correct `if` statements that check every value around the point. There really is no place for a loop :) You will check 8 * 8 = 64 points around, which is wrong.

Also, your `if` statement doesn't run when the point is at 0 0 (or near an edge), you can easily fix that by putting the condition inside the `if` statements:

```
if (row > 0 && col > 0 && generation.get(row - 1, col - 1)) //...
if (row > 0 && generation.get(row - 1, col)) //...
//Continue...
```

Comment: You should probably also check to see if you're on the right or bottom edges of the array, too.

Comment: @Xenotod Yes, true. That is left as an exercise :)

Comment: Awesome! I actually removed the for loop right after posting this and viola! it worked. I appreciate the help! I will be checking for the edges now (: